# how to compare corresponding metrics in prometheus?

Tags: ruby, prometheus

lets say i have two corresponding tables, table1 and table2, in my database, one-to-one. for creation of each record in each table there is a metric. now, is it possible two use these two metrics(one from table1 and one from table2) to have na information how many records in table1 DOESNT have a corresponding record in table2 in a given moment? can i pass id of the record into metrics somehow?

Comment: This question is difficult to understand, maybe at least add the table schema and any code you have already tried.

Answer (score 1):

If you're generating metrics for every record and each record has a unique identifier (i.e. label), then you can use the `count` and `by` aggregators. For example, `count(table_metric{id="foo"}) by (table)` would work if they each have a table label.

If the metric names are different, you'll probably want to use the `or` operator to create a union. For example, `count(table_1_metric or table_2_metric) by (id)`.

In either case, if you want an entry in both tables, you'll want to check to make sure the count is 2.

Finally, just my two cents, but I wouldn't recommend making a habit of putting such high cardinality data into Prometheus. An alternative way of doing this would involve using something like [this SQL exporter](https://github.com/free/sql_exporter) to generate metrics based off database queries (e.g. `SELECT count(*) FROM T1 LEFT JOIN T2 ON T1.ID = T2.ID WHERE T2.ID IS NULL`, which would show you how many don't match so you could investigate further).